# jQuery contains selector does not work on large attribute in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'am using a jQuery contains selector which looks like that:

```
jQuery('.myClass[attrA="de.namespace.type"] div[data-data*=\'is_my_requiredItem":true\']').addClass('XYZ');
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome. In IE it works until the content of the attribute "data-data" gets too big (round about 15k characters). I can not make the content smaller at the moment and the only unique identifier is contained within the attribute.

Is there a workaround for IE11?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe a `.each` loop checking the value of `.attr('data-data')`?

Comment: What happens when it "doesn't work" ?

Comment: In the case of "doesn't work", the class (addClass()) is not added.

Comment: So it doesn't just use an inordinate amount of time to parse way to big attributes, it doesn't work at all. There shouldn't be any limit on the size of an attribute, but jQuery has to get those attributes and parse them, selectors like that are inherently slow, but should work.

Comment: How is the data attribute set?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 You mean "data-data" attribute? It is not set manually and originated by loading the page.

Comment: Yes. I mean `data-data`. So it's set in HTML with `<div data-data="...............">`?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Yes

Comment: OK, I have an idea - something that *may* work. I'll prepare an answer.